# How to use Flutter hive for creating a mark as fabourite button?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a Quotes app as a beginner Practice project in flutter. I have multiple pages in my app. Right now I want to create an icon button which will perform as a bookmark (Mark as favourite) for the user.And in the app bar there will be a favourite option where the user can find those marked page number.Local databse seems too confusing to me.How can i use Hive for that problem.

```
class p1 extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _p1State createState() => _p1State();
  }

class _p1State extends State<p1> {
bool _isFavorite = true;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
   body:Stack(
       children:<Widget>[
       Image(
       image:AssetImage("Image/Chowsun1.jpg"),
       fit:BoxFit.cover,
       width: double.infinity,
       height: double.infinity,
   ),
      Align(alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text('  Hello world '
              ,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: "Explora",
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900 ) )



      ),
         Align(
           alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
           child: const Text('   1 ',
             style: TextStyle(
                 fontSize: 25.0,
                 fontFamily: "MonteCarlo",
                 color: Colors.white,
                 fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
           ),



         ),
    Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: FavoriteButton(
          isFavorite: _isFavorite,
          iconSize: 40,
          iconDisabledColor: Colors.red,
          iconColor: Colors.white,
          valueChanged: (isFav) {setState(() { _isFavorite = isFav; });},
        )
    )])

  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bookmark or add favorites you need to persist the quotes. For that, you need to add these two packages https://pub.dev/packages/hive and https://pub.dev/packages/hive_flutter. What you are asking is for the whole code so I suggest you go through this easy documentation for hive implementation. https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/README

For a quick overview refer to this code.

After initializing `await Hive.initFlutter();` and opening a box `await Hive.openBox('testBox');` in `main()`.

Make a box reference in your respective class then add the value `box.put('key', 'Value');` Hive stores data in key-value pairs.